# Converter String com data para DateTime em Java

Tags: java, datetime

Tenho um arquivo CSV e nele tem uma coluna com a String:

```
"Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014"
```

Preciso passar os dados do CSV para uma tabela MySQL. Sendo assim, preciso converter essa string para o formato DateTime para que eu consiga inserir essa string como uma DateTime no MySQL.

Como fazer essa conversão?

Comment: Já tentou algo antes e deu erro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa fazer é olhar a documentação de formatação de datas. Você pode fazer isto vendo a documentação de [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Abaixo, o significado apenas dos padrões que serão necessários no nosso caso:

- `E`: nome do dia na semana;
- `M`: mês do ano;
- `d`: dia do mês
- `H`: hora do dia, de 0 a 24, usaremos `HH`;
- `m`: minuto na hora, sendo `mm`;
- `s`: segundo no minuto, sendo `ss`;
- `z`: *time zone*;
- `y`: ano, no seu caso como está representado com 4 algarismos, precisamos usar `yyyy`;

Então, geraríamos o seguinte padrão:

```
EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

Além deste padrão, ao criarmos o [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) precisaremos informar o *locale*, pois por padrão é recuperado o *locale* padrão para formatação (`Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`). No padrão poderíamos usar qualquer *locale* da lingua inglesa, como abaixo:

```java
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Um exemplo completo gerando uma instância de Date ficaria assim:

```java
final String dateStr = "Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014";
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
final Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
// faça o que for preciso com "date"
```

Com um `Date` em mãos você pode inserí-lo no banco, por exemplo construindo um [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) a partir dele:

```java
final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente você precisa fazer o parser de datetime, Como esse exemplo:

```
public void Dados(String dado) {  // Obtem o time em Wed, etc..
    try {  
        this.dado = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")  
                          .format(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US).parse(dado));  // Faz o Parser de resposta
```

Para Obter o time com dias da semana em PT-BR remova o ', Locale.US), Assim o script Irá obter timezone do pedido feito.

**A String Precisa ter o nome do dia na linguagem setada, Por exemplo em BRT: Qua, Sex, Sab**

De outro modo o 'z' pode ser retirado e o TimeZone já setado no script, Fazendo com que o pedido seja normalmente visto como o Valor do TimeZone;

Como por exemplo utilizando: a = TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT")

Caso não seja setado, Será utilizado um 'locale' para atribuir a outro TimeZone o valor do time.

**Referência: *http://www.guj.com.br/java/245280-resolvido-erro-ao-converter-string-para-data***

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para atualizar as respostas (que não estão erradas), a partir do Java 8 você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) para manipular datas.

Esta API funciona de maneira similar, mas há [algumas diferenças importantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) com relação a `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`. A principal é que há menos comportamentos implícitos (muitos comuns com `SimpleDateFormat`) e por isso a primeira impressão é que ela é mais "complicada", por exigir um entendimento maior de como funcionam as datas.

Por exemplo, a abreviação do timezone ("BRT", que [corresponde a "Brasília Time"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brt) - o famoso Horário de Brasília) é uma informação ambígua. Por isso as abreviações não são consideradas timezones de fato, justamente [por não serem padronizadas e haver muita ambiguidade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231). Entre os exemplos, temos "IST", que é usada na Índia, Irlanda e Israel, ou "CST", que é usada na China, Cuba e Estados Unidos.

Por terem muitas abreviações ambíguas, nem sempre é possível obter um único timezone correspondente. O único jeito de não ter um timezone ambíguo é usar a [nomenclatura da IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). A abreviação BRT, por exemplo, corresponde ao timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` (a IANA usa o nome do continente e da cidade mais populosa da região para nomear os timezones), mas também corresponde a `America/Recife`, que durante parte do ano é igual a `America/Sao_Paulo`, mas é diferente durante o horário de verão - aliás, durante o horário de verão a abreviação muda para BRST (Brasília Summer Time), mas só nos estados que seguem as mesmas regras de `America/Sao_Paulo`. Nos que seguem `America/Recife` continua sendo BRT, pois estes não tem horário de verão (segundo as regras atuais).

*Por apresentarem estas diferenças durante o ano, a IANA considera que `America/Sao_Paulo` e `America/Recife` são dois timezones diferentes. O fato de eles terem o mesmo horário - e a mesma abreviação - durante parte do ano é apenas um detalhe.*

Enfim, eu só disse tudo isso porque `SimpleDateFormat` simplesmente assume algum timezone quando é passada uma abreviação (e em casos de ambiguidade não há como controlar qual será usado). Já na nova API temos que especificar qual timezone queremos usar.

---

Outra diferença é que há vários tipos diferentes para representar datas: um somente com o dia, mês e ano, outro só com o horário, outro com data, hora e timezone, etc. Por isso deve-se escolher o tipo adequado de acordo com os dados que você está trabalhando.

No caso, a string de entrada possui data, hora e timezone, então o tipo indicado é [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Para transformar a string em uma data, usa-se um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). E para configurar o timezone a ser usado (pois a abreviação é ambígua e devemos setar um timezone), usa-se um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html).

Para setar o timezone, usa-se um [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) com o nome do timezone no formato da IANA. É possível passar vários timezones, por isso estes são colocados em um `java.util.Set`:

```
// timezone a ser usado para a abreviação
Set<ZoneId> zones = new HashSet<>();
zones.add(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));

// criar o DateTimeFormatter
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // data e hora
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
    // abreviação do timezone (usar java.time.format.TextStyle)
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, zones)
    // ano
    .appendPattern(" uuuu")
    // usar locale inglês para o dia da semana e mês
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
// transformar a string em data
ZonedDateTime datetime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014", fmt);
```

Repare que usei o `java.util.Locale` correspondente ao idioma inglês, pois o dia da semana e o mês estão em inglês. Se você não especificar um locale, será usado a configuração *default* da JVM, e nem sempre pode ser o idioma que você precisa. É melhor setar o locale se você já sabe qual o idioma usado.

Para entender melhor o que são as letras `EEE MMM ...`, veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). Muita atenção porque nem tudo é igual a `SimpleDateFormat`. Algumas letras funcionam da mesma maneira, outras de maneira parecida, outras de maneira completamente diferente, etc.

---

Para salvar no banco, você pode converter para um `java.sql.Timestamp`, por exemplo. No Java 8 foram adicionados métodos de conversão para facilitar. O método `from` recebe um `java.time.Instant`, que pode ser obtido a partir do `ZonedDateTime` usando o método `toInstant()`:

```
// converter para java.sql.Timestamp
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(datetime.toInstant());
```

E para converter de volta para `ZonedDateTime`, usamos o método `toInstant()`, que retorna um `Instant`, e em seguida o método `atZone`, que converte o `Instant` para o timezone indicado:

```
// converter Timestamp para ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime zdt = ts.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

E é possível obter a string original usando o mesmo `DateTimeFormatter` para formatar a data:

```
String dateStr = zdt.format(fmt);
```

---

Caso o banco que você está usando tenha um driver compatível com o **JDBC 4.2**, é possível trabalhar diretamente com o `Instant`, usando os métodos `setObject` da classe [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) e `getObject` da classe [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...
// seta o java.time.Instant
ps.setObject(1, datetime.toInstant());

// obter o Instant do banco
ResultSet rs = ...
Instant instant = rs.getObject(1, Instant.class);
// converter o instant para o timezone
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```